# DevExpress ASPxGridViewDataCheckColumn Uncheck Every Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I want to uncheck every row in my GridViewDataCheckColumn. 
Is there a property I can set? or do I need to loop through each row in that column and uncheck it in c# code?
There doesnt seem to be an obvious solution to do this in code.

Answer (score 0):

I just handled this in SQL and c#.

```
String val = "0";
String updateSQL = "UPDATE table SET column='{0}'", val);
```

and then execute the SQL code within c#.